# Edited visudo, now not able to use any sudo commands

Tags: sudo

New to Unix and shell scripting,
Updated visudo with

```
username ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWDMDS : /path/name
```

Now not able to edit sudo, visudo or use any sudo command.

how can I restore to previous state?

when i try

```
visudo
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
visudo: /etc/sudoers: Permission denied
```

when I try

```
sudo
sudo: >>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 62 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 62
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

Comment: You might be totally hosed unless you know root's actual password and can do `su -`

Comment: You can try booting a live system and edit `/etc/sudoers`

Comment: What type / distribution of "Unix" is this, exactly?

Comment: It is a remote cloud developer desktop.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, to answer your question straight-up, @Tablemaker and @guillermochamorro are on the right track.  Some possible options are:

- log in via a privileged ssh key, if you have key-based logins enabled for root
- log in via an admin account and use the `su` command to become root, if you know the current root password
- have someone else do one of the above, if they have the key or password, but you don't
- if you're in a hosting environment, you (or someone else) may have some means of resetting the root password to a known password, whereupon you can go the `su` route mentioned above

For future readers who may have physical access to the machine, it could also be possible to boot from a live CD or USB stick (or even PXE boot, if you happen to have that infrastructure available), and fix your sudoers file.

In the hope that an ounce of prevention is worth a pound of cure, I would like to offer this note for future readers who may be about to do what you just did.  :)

It is possible that you had the opportunity to **avoid** this problem entirely, but ignored it.

Some implementations of `visudo` check the file's syntax after you save the `sudoers` file, and alert you to problems that are detected:

```
$ sudo visudo
(edit file to add the line given in your example, then type ZZ to save & exit)
/usr/local/etc/sudoers.tmp: 36 lines, 773 characters
>>> /usr/local/etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 36 <<<
What now?
```

Here we see that `visudo` has detected problems in your `sudoers` file and is asking you what to do about them.  Pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd> gives a brief synopsis of the available options:

```
Options are:
  (e)dit sudoers file again
  e(x)it without saving changes to sudoers file
  (Q)uit and save changes to sudoers file (DANGER!)

What now?
```

Obviously, <kbd>e</kbd> will return you to the editor to correct the error in your file.  If after saving, the syntax warning appears again, the <kbd>x</kbd> option is advisable, to leave the sudoers file unchanged while you go research the correct syntax that your change requires.

The <kbd>Q</kbd> option is highly inadvisable (hence the **DANGER!** warning), and results in the case you have now: a non-functional `sudo` installation.