# Can not edit sudoers file

Tags: ubuntu, sudo

I'd like to delete a line in the file "sudoers", but I'm not able to edit the file, I get an error :

```
****@****:~$ sudo vim /etc/sudoers
>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line 16 <<<
sudo: parse error in /etc/sudoers near line 16
sudo: no valid sudoers sources found, quitting
sudo: unable to initialize policy plugin
```

I tried two solutions that it doesn't work :

- Copy the file in the home directory to edit them.
- Using the commande `pkexec visudo` : `>>> /etc/sudoers: syntax error near line`

Comment: Do you have any other way of becoming root? `su`?

Comment: What exactly do you want to achieve by deleting that specific line?

Comment: Boot in rescue mode, and delete the line. Or boot using a live CD/usb , mount the partition holding the /etc/sudoers and delete the line. And, to avoid this in the future, **do not edit "manually"** this file. Use the command `visudo` instead.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/535771/edited-visudo-now-not-able-to-use-any-sudo-commands

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you run `sudo cat /etc/sudoers` (or `pkexec cat /etc/sudoers`) you should see, near the top of the output, a warning that says,

> # This file MUST be edited with the 'visudo' command as root

In other words, under ***normal circumstances***, you should run `sudo visudo` or `pkexec visudo`. As the [visudo manpage](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/visudo.8.html) will tell you,

> **visudo** edits the sudoers file in a safe fashion, analogous to vipw(8).  visudo locks the sudoers file against multiple simultaneous edits, provides basic sanity checks, and checks for parse errors.
>   If you edit the file using, e.g. `sudo vim /etc/sudoers`, you don't get the benefit of visudo's syntax checking.

***If the normal process does not work***, you may need to boot from a live CD or USB, mount the partition where `/etc/sudoers` is located and delete the invalid line. Note that `visudo -c` or `visudo --check` allows you to check the syntax without actually modifying the file.

Comment: The OP isn't going to be able to run `sudo` to see this.

Comment: Looks like the OP has `pkexec` has an alternative to `sudo`, so they might be able to `pkexec visudo`; I'm trying to work out if the reported `syntax error` is a fatal or just a warning.

Comment: @roaima I haven't tested `pkexec` on Ubuntu, but when I run it only MX Linux (which is also based on Debian), I get a dialog (instead of a command line prompt) asking for the password. This is why I refrained from adding it.

Comment: OK. Feel free to roll-back. Sorry.

Comment: Also https://askubuntu.com/a/1053617/473234 for `pkexec` (shakes head).